# GPS-Service , Main Activity and Map Activity (Pass co-ordinates from service to map current location)

Tags: android, android-mapview, geofencing

I am new to android and try to implement an activity with two tab one show co-ordinates which i got from GPS-Service and i want to mark that current location (co-ordinates value using marker) in map using coordinates value which i got from GPS services.  And kindly help me for implementing Geo Fencing in map also.

GPS Service

```html
package com.app.servicegps;

/**
 * Created by Android on 29-Dec-16.
 */

import android.app.Service;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.location.Location;
import android.location.LocationListener;
import android.location.LocationManager;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.IBinder;
import android.provider.Settings;
import android.support.annotation.Nullable;


public class GPS_Service extends Service {

    private LocationListener listener;

    private LocationManager locationManager;

    @Nullable

    @Override

    public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
        return null;
    }

    @Override

    public void onCreate() {

        listener = new LocationListener() {
            @Override
            public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
                Intent i = new Intent("location_update");
                i.putExtra("coordinatesLongt",location.getLongitude());
                i.putExtra("coordinatesLangt",location.getLatitude());
                sendBroadcast(i);
            }

            @Override
            public void onStatusChanged(String s, int i, Bundle bundle) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onProviderEnabled(String s) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onProviderDisabled(String s) {
                Intent i = new Intent(Settings.ACTION_LOCATION_SOURCE_SETTINGS);
                i.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
                startActivity(i);
            }
        };

        locationManager = (LocationManager) getApplicationContext().getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);

        //noinspection MissingPermission
        locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER,3000,0,listener);

    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
        if(locationManager != null){
            //noinspection MissingPermission
            locationManager.removeUpdates(listener);
        }
    }
}
```

Map Activity

```html
package com.app.servicegps;

import android.content.BroadcastReceiver;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.DialogInterface;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.IntentFilter;
import android.hardware.Sensor;
import android.hardware.SensorEvent;
import android.hardware.SensorEventListener;
import android.location.Location;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import com.google.android.gms.common.ConnectionResult;
import com.google.android.gms.common.GooglePlayServicesUtil;
import com.google.android.gms.location.LocationListener;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.CameraUpdateFactory;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.GoogleMap;

import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.BitmapDescriptorFactory;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.LatLng;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.MarkerOptions;

import com.google.android.gms.maps.CameraUpdateFactory;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.GoogleMap;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.OnMapReadyCallback;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.LatLng;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.Marker;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.MarkerOptions;

public class MapsActivity extends FragmentActivity implements LocationListener,OnMapReadyCallback,
        SensorEventListener, DialogInterface.OnClickListener {

    private GoogleMap mMap;
    private BroadcastReceiver broadcastReceiver;
    Marker now;
    String langt = null;
    String longt= null;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        setContentView(R.layout.activity_maps);

        // Obtain the SupportMapFragment and get notified when the map is ready to be used.

        SupportMapFragment mapFragment = (SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager()

                .findFragmentById(R.id.map);

        mapFragment.getMapAsync(this);

    }
    @Override
    public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {

        if(now != null){
            now.remove();

        }

        //TextView tvLocation = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tv_location);

        // Getting latitude of the current location
        //double latitude = location.getLatitude();

        // Getting longitude of the current location
       // double longitude = location.getLongitude();
        double latitude= Double.parseDouble(langt);
        double longitude= Double.parseDouble(longt);
        // Creating a LatLng object for the current location
       // LatLng latLng = new LatLng(latitude, longitude);
        LatLng latLng = new LatLng(latitude, longitude);

        now = mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(latLng));
        // Showing the current location in Google Map
        mMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(latLng));

        // Zoom in the Google Map
        mMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.zoomTo(15));

    }

    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        if(broadcastReceiver == null){
            broadcastReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
                @Override
                public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

                    //get value
                    if(intent.getAction().equals("location_update"))
                    {
                        langt=intent.getStringExtra("coordinatesLangt");
                        longt=intent.getStringExtra("coordinatesLongt");
                    }

                }
            };
        }
        registerReceiver(broadcastReceiver,new IntentFilter("location_update"));
    }

    /**
     * Manipulates the map once available.
     * This callback is triggered when the map is ready to be used.
     * This is where we can add markers or lines, add listeners or move the camera. In this case,
     * we just add a marker near Sydney, Australia.
     * If Google Play services is not installed on the device, the user will be prompted to install
     * it inside the SupportMapFragment. This method will only be triggered once the user has
     * installed Google Play services and returned to the app.
     */
    @Override
    public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {
        mMap = googleMap;

        // Add a marker in Sydney and move the camera

       /* LatLng sydney = new LatLng(-34, 151);
        mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(sydney).title("Marker in Sydney"));
        mMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(sydney));*/

    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onSensorChanged(SensorEvent event) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onAccuracyChanged(Sensor sensor, int accuracy) {

    }
}
```

Main Activity

```html
package com.app.servicegps;

import android.Manifest;
import android.content.BroadcastReceiver;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.IntentFilter;
import android.content.pm.PackageManager;
import android.os.Build;
import android.support.annotation.NonNull;
import android.support.v4.content.ContextCompat;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private Button btn_start, btn_stop;
    private TextView textView;
    private BroadcastReceiver broadcastReceiver;

    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        if(broadcastReceiver == null){
            broadcastReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
                @Override
                public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

                    textView.append("\n" +intent.getExtras().get("coordinates"));

                }
            };
        }
        registerReceiver(broadcastReceiver,new IntentFilter("location_update"));
    }

    @Override
    protected void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
        if(broadcastReceiver != null){
            unregisterReceiver(broadcastReceiver);
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        btn_start = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button);
        btn_stop = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button2);
        textView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView);

        if(!runtime_permissions())
            enable_buttons();

    }

    private void enable_buttons() {

        btn_start.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Intent i =new Intent(getApplicationContext(),GPS_Service.class);
                startService(i);
            }
        });

        btn_stop.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {

                Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),GPS_Service.class);
                stopService(i);

            }
        });

    }

    private boolean runtime_permissions() {
        if(Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 23 && ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED && ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED){

            requestPermissions(new String[]{Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION},100);

            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }


    @Override
    public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, @NonNull String[] permissions, @NonNull int[] grantResults) {
        super.onRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permissions, grantResults);
        if(requestCode == 100){
            if( grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED && grantResults[1] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED){
                enable_buttons();
            }else {
                runtime_permissions();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Kindly help me for Geo fencing how i implement it it map activity.
The basic this i want is a main activity with tabs fragments.
Fragment 1st - Show Coordinates 
Fragment 2nd Show Map

And A Geo Fencing To Show Notification when i enter in a tag place.

Comment: Use Interface to update marker

Answer (score 0):

**Interface class**

```
    public interface LocationInter {
    void onUpdateLocation(Location  location);
}
```

**Implement the interface in main activity.**

**Add below lines in GPS service class.**

```
  private static LocationInter locationListener = null;

   public void LocationInstance(LocationGuideInter locationListeners) {
        if (locationListener == null) {
            locationListener = locationListeners;
        }
    }
```

**In Location change add this line**

```
 if (locationListener != null) {
                locationListener.onUpdateLocation(location);
            }
```

Answer (score 0):

This is taken from android documentation so you can look at more details [here](https://developer.android.com/training/location/geofencing.html)

**Set up for Geofence Monitoring**

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION"/>
```

**Create geofence objects**
 Use Geofence.Builder to create a geofence, setting the desired radius, duration, and transition types for the geofence. For example, to populate a list object named mGeofenceList:

```
mGeofenceList.add(new Geofence.Builder()
// Set the request ID of the geofence. This is a string to identify this
// geofence.
.setRequestId(entry.getKey())

.setCircularRegion(
        entry.getValue().latitude,
        entry.getValue().longitude,
        Constants.GEOFENCE_RADIUS_IN_METERS
)
.setExpirationDuration(Constants.GEOFENCE_EXPIRATION_IN_MILLISECONDS)
.setTransitionTypes(Geofence.GEOFENCE_TRANSITION_ENTER |
        Geofence.GEOFENCE_TRANSITION_EXIT)
.build());
```

**Specify geofences and initial triggers**

```
private GeofencingRequest getGeofencingRequest() {
GeofencingRequest.Builder builder = new GeofencingRequest.Builder();
builder.setInitialTrigger(GeofencingRequest.INITIAL_TRIGGER_ENTER);
builder.addGeofences(mGeofenceList);
return builder.build();
```

}

**Define an Intent for geofence transitions**

```
public class MainActivity extends FragmentActivity {
...
private PendingIntent getGeofencePendingIntent() {
    // Reuse the PendingIntent if we already have it.
    if (mGeofencePendingIntent != null) {
        return mGeofencePendingIntent;
    }
    Intent intent = new Intent(this, GeofenceTransitionsIntentService.class);
    // We use FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT so that we get the same pending intent back when
    // calling addGeofences() and removeGeofences().
    return PendingIntent.getService(this, 0, intent, PendingIntent.
            FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
}
```

**Add geofences**

```
 public class MainActivity extends FragmentActivity {
        ...
        LocationServices.GeofencingApi.addGeofences(
                    mGoogleApiClient,
                    getGeofencingRequest(),
                    getGeofencePendingIntent()
            ).setResultCallback(this);
}
```

**Handle Geofence Transitions**

```
public class GeofenceTransitionsIntentService extends IntentService {

 protected void onHandleIntent(Intent intent) {
    GeofencingEvent geofencingEvent = GeofencingEvent.fromIntent(intent);
    if (geofencingEvent.hasError()) {
        String errorMessage = GeofenceErrorMessages.getErrorString(this,
                geofencingEvent.getErrorCode());
        Log.e(TAG, errorMessage);
        return;
    }

    // Get the transition type.
    int geofenceTransition = geofencingEvent.getGeofenceTransition();

    // Test that the reported transition was of interest.
    if (geofenceTransition == Geofence.GEOFENCE_TRANSITION_ENTER ||
            geofenceTransition == Geofence.GEOFENCE_TRANSITION_EXIT) {

        // Get the geofences that were triggered. A single event can trigger
        // multiple geofences.
        List triggeringGeofences = geofencingEvent.getTriggeringGeofences();

        // Get the transition details as a String.
        String geofenceTransitionDetails = getGeofenceTransitionDetails(
                this,
                geofenceTransition,
                triggeringGeofences
        );

        // Send notification and log the transition details.
        sendNotification(geofenceTransitionDetails);
        Log.i(TAG, geofenceTransitionDetails);
    } else {
        // Log the error.
        Log.e(TAG, getString(R.string.geofence_transition_invalid_type,
                geofenceTransition));
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Geofences tutorial from Raywendrlich  [here](https://www.raywenderlich.com/103540/geofences-googleapiclient)